# Finding the number of particles per unit area along a given plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

We are given a problem in our class that goes like this:

> In a simple cubic lattice constant $0.287$ nm, the number of atoms per $\text{mm}^2$ along the plane $111$ is

- $2.11\times 10^{13}$
- $1.73\times 10^{13}$
- $1.29\times 10^{13}$
- $1.21\times 10^{13}$

---

On plotting a figure it is clear that one atom at the corner contributes $1/6$ of its area to one unit cell and a total of $3$ of them are on this plane. So
$$\text{No. of atom} \  \ N_{111}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot 3=\frac{1}{2}$$
The area of a triangle given by
$$A_{111}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(\sqrt{2}a)^2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a^2$$
And so the number of atoms per mm$^2$
$$\frac{N_{111}}{A_{111}}=\frac{1/2}{(\sqrt{3}/2)a^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\times (0.287)^2}\times 10^{9}=7.01\times 10^{12}  \ \text{atom}/\text{mm}^2$$
But there is no option with such a value.
Can anyone point out the mistake if any?

Comment: If it were a body-centered cubic lattice, instead of a simple cubic, then I think the 2.11 answer would work, because you would get one extra atom in the triangle.  You're certain it's a simple cubic?

Comment: I'm certain it's given a simple cubic but the answer (a) is correct as according to the answer sheet.